# Reboiling water and reheating chulent on shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul, electricity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blackout restoration on Shabbath - and your food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17530/blackout-restoration-on-shabbath-and-your-food)

Last night, after we had all gone to sleep, there was a power outage. From reports in the community, it seems that the power was off for at least 4 hours. It went back on this morning.

I have a hot water pot plugged directly into the wall. I had filled it and turned it on and the water was hot before shabbos started. But overnight, it clearly went off and cooled completely, and when the power came back, it started to "cook" again, on shabbos. Can I use that water on shabbos?

The chulent in the crockpot probably didn't cool completely, but certainly cooled off some and then restarted. Is the wet chulent allowed to be eaten?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17530/759

Comment: yup -- feel free to close. that one didn't come up in my search. sad that the water aspect of the other question hasn't been answered. thanks.